About the Sobolev space $H^{s,p}$ in Wong.
For $-\infty<s<\infty$ and $1\leq p<\infty$, we define $H^{s,p}=\left\{u\in \mathcal{S}': \mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u}(\xi))\in L^p\right\}$
The space $H^{s,p}$ is a normed vector space if we equip it with the norm $\left\|u\right\|_{s,p}:=\left\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u}(\xi))\right\|_{p}$
(Definition from the book introduction to pseudo differential operators by Wong)
Question If $\left\|u\right\|_{s,p}=0$ then $u=0$? why? (I'am confussed with the fact which $u$ is a tempered distribution...)
Thanks

This is by the fact that the Fourier transform defines an isomorphism from $\mathcal{S}'$ to itself.

but i can't see the intermediate steps.
$\left|u\right|_{s,p}=0\Rightarrow \int |\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+|\xi|^2))^{s/2}\widehat{u})|^p=0\Rightarrow  \mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+|\xi|^2))^{s/2}\widehat{u})=0 a.e.\rightarrow (1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u}=0\Rightarrow \widehat{u}=0\Rightarrow u=0$. Right?
My confussion is originated from, if $|\xi|^2\widehat{u}=0$, then $u$ is a polynomial in $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$.

That's because you don't want to conclude that $(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\hat{u}(\xi)=0$ a.e., but rather that it's zero in the sense of tempered distributions; then since  $(1+|\xi|^2)^{-s/2}$ is a smooth function with enough decay, we can multiply by it and obtain another element in $\mathcal{S}'$ (you can't do this with $|\xi|^{-s}$, which is where the polynomials come in; here you can only conclude that the support of $\hat{u}$ is at the origin, and so $\hat{u}$ is a linear combination of derivatives of $\delta$ masses at the origin).
